# How can you print the reference/tag for a bibliography item as well as the bibitem in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I will start with the context: I am preparing to sit some online examinations and am creating a reference file for the document which I will write my exams into. This will make it easy for me to reference using LaTeX during the exam and get an auto-compiled bibliography.

My reference file has a `main.tex` file with some key term definitions and summaries of my sources, and a `refs.bib` file with the references themselves. I would like to print this and have it on my desk when I am writing the exam. I will copy the `refs.bib` file into the the LaTeX document I will use in the exam. However in order to make good references quickly I need to read off from my printout the 'tag' which you use to access a reference.

I am new to the TeX side of StackExchange, but I have tried to create a MWEB here.
bibtex file:

```
@book{book1,
author = "Anon",
title = "Anon's Adventures"}
```

Then, in the main.tex file,

```
text text text \cite{book1}
...
\printbibliography
```

with the intended effect that the bibliography prints like this

`Anon. *Anon's Adventures*. Ref: book1`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `style=reading`. That will also print the key.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633215/35864 seems like it could help.

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550729/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51161/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/610125/35864